# How to bind collection of objects to a custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has a datagrid in it and I want to be able to bind an ItemsSource to that datagrid but I can't seem to get it to work. I have an ObservableObjectCollection set up as a dependency property but I get the error "Cannot convert binding to ObservableObjectCollection" when I try to run it.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", GetType(ObservableObjectCollection), GetType(HomePageControl), New PropertyMetadata(New ObservableObjectCollection()))

Public Property ItemsSourceCollection As ObservableObjectCollection
        Get
            Return DirectCast(Me.GetValue(HomePageControl.ItemsSourceProperty), ObservableObjectCollection)
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableObjectCollection)
            Me.SetValue(HomePageControl.ItemsSourceProperty, value)
        End Set
End Property
```

Am I defining the dependency property wrong? I see a lot of answers to questions similar to this and they all say to use a dependency property. What gives? I'm using the ObservableObjectCollection because I don't know what type of object will be bound to the control.

Comment: Please, provide the code/XAML that sets the binding. If it is a real Custom Control, bring the ControlTemplate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapper properties for dependency properties should have the same name as the dependency property, i.e. 'ItemsSource' instead of 'ItemsSourceCollection'.

This is a XAML rule. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist). It's written for WPF, but it is also true for Silverlight.

> Again, by convention, the name of the wrapper property must be the same as the name chosen and given as first parameter of the Register call that registered the property. If your property does not follow the convention, this does not necessarily disable all possible uses, but you will encounter several notable issues

Comment: This actually was the issue that I was having with the error, which I fixed last night but left the question up to see if anyone knew why. Now I'm having an issue that the collection is not getting filled...

Comment: @BarryFranklin I've updated the post to include the prooflink.